# How to tell Android relative layout to take all space left betwean two elements. Does not matter how much is that space

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

How to tell Android relative layout to take all space left between two elements. Does not matter how much is that space.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">



<TableLayout android:layout_below="@id/title_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id = "@+id/usb_config_title">

    <TableRow android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
        <TextView android:layout_width="398dp"
            android:layout_height="4px"
            android:text="     "/>
        <TextView android:layout_width="4px"
            android:layout_height="4px"
            android:text="     "
            android:background="@color/title_background"/>
        <TextView android:layout_width="398dp"
            android:layout_height="4px"
            android:text="     "/>
    </TableRow>


    <TableRow android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
        <TextView android:text="@string/usb_stick"
            android:layout_width="398dp" 

            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="22dp"/>
        <TextView android:layout_width="4px"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="     "
            android:background="@color/title_background"/>
        <TextView android:text = "@string/usb_internal_memory"

        android:layout_width="398dp" 
            android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="22dp"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
        <TextView android:layout_width="398dp"
            android:layout_height="5px"
            android:text="     "/>
        <TextView android:layout_width="4px"
            android:layout_height="5px"
            android:text="     "
            android:background="@color/title_background"/>
        <TextView android:layout_width="398dp"
            android:layout_height="5px"
            android:text="     "/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>


<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_below="@id/usb_config_title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list3"
        android:layout_width="398px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    />

    <TextView android:layout_width="4px"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="     "
        android:background="@color/title_background"/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list4"
        android:layout_width="398px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    />
</LinearLayout>
<include layout="@layout/buttons_bottom_with_relative"/>      
</RelativeLayout>
```

So i need id/list3 to last till button bar which is. At the moment id/list3 is covered by button bar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/controls" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
    style="@android:style/ButtonBar"
    android:background="@drawable/bottom_layout_selector"
>
    <Button 
        android:layout_width="100px" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:text="@string/start" 
        android:visibility="invisible"
    />

    <Button 
        android:layout_width="100px" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:id="@+id/stopButton"
        android:text="@string/stop" 
        android:visibility="invisible"
    />

    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:id="@+id/nextButton"
        android:text="@string/next"
        android:visibility="invisible"
    />

    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:id="@+id/resetStatistics"
        android:text="@string/reset_statistics"
        android:visibility="invisible" 
    />

    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:id="@+id/histogramSettings"
        android:text="@string/histogram_settings"
        android:visibility="invisible" 
    />

    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:id="@+id/saveButton"
        android:text="@string/save"
        android:visibility="invisible"
    />

    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:id="@+id/loadConfig"
        android:text="@string/load_config"
        android:visibility="invisible" 
    />

    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:id="@+id/saveConfig"
        android:text="@string/save_config"
        android:visibility="invisible" 
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you give some further information on the question, perhaps even show the XML for your layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding this to the linear layout that includes list3

```
    android:layout_below="@id/usb_config_title"
    android:layout_above="@id/controls"
```

So the linear layout positions itself between those two.

I don't think you can use the weight attribute for Relative layouts.  If you align one layout to the top of the screen and one to the bottom then tell the one in the middle to above and below the other two it should fill in the space

Comment: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_above' with value '@id/controls'). Even if i edit the line '<include layout="@layout/buttons_bottom_with_relative" android:id = "@+id/controls"/>' at the end of layout file.

Comment: Ah ok, it can only refer to ids listed above itself.  So the linear layout with the list will need to be listed at the end of the file rather than the middle

Comment: Wow, I can't believe it was so simple and yet this combination of attributes never struck me as a potential solution. This worked perfectly. If I could give more than +1, I absolutely would.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably need is to set the layout_weight property of the Relative Layout, and the whole thing to be within a LinearLayout. If you could show us the XML you have so far we can see for sure!